# Spark is taking too much time and creating thousands of jobs for some tasks

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Machine Config :

- RAM: 16 gb
- Processor: 4 cores(Xeon E3 3.3 GHz)

Problem:

- Time Consuming : Taking more than 18 minutes

Case Scenario :

- > Spark Mode: Local
- Database: Using Cassandra 2.1.12

I am fetching 3 tables into dataframes , which is having less than 10 rows. yes, less than 10 (ten). 
After fetching it into dataframes I performing joins,count,show and collect operation many times. When I execute my program Spark is creating 40404 jobs 4 times. it indicates that count requires to perform those jobs. I am using count 4-5 times in program. After waiting for more than 18 minutes(approx 18.5 to 20) it gives me expected output.

- why Spark is creating that much of jobs?
- is it obvious ('ok') to take this much time (18 minutes) to execute this number of jobs(40404 * 4 approx)?

Thanks in advance.

Sample code 1:

```scala
def getGroups(id: Array[String], level: Int): DataFrame = {
    var lvl = level
    if (level >= 0) {
      for (iterated_id <- id) {
        val single_level_group = supportive_df.filter("id = '" + iterated_id + "' and level = " + level).select("family_id")
        //single_level_group.show()
        intermediate_df = intermediate_df.unionAll(single_level_group)
        //println("for loop portion...")
      }
      final_df = final_df.unionAll(intermediate_df)
      lvl -= 1
      val user_id_param = intermediate_df.collect().map { row => row.getString(0) }
      intermediate_df = empty_df
      //println("new method...if portion...")
      getGroups(user_id_param, lvl)
    } else {
      //println("new method...")
      final_df.distinct()
    }
  }
```

Sample code 2:

```scala
 setGetGroupsVars("u_id", user_id.toString(), sa_user_df)
  var user_belong_groups: DataFrame = empty_df
  val user_array = Array[String](user_id.toString())

  val user_levels = sa_user_df.filter("id = '" + user_id + "'").select("level").distinct().collect().map { x => x.getInt(0) }

  println(user_levels.length+"...rapak")
  println(user_id.toString())
  for (u_lvl <- user_levels) {
    val x1 = getGroups(user_array, u_lvl)
    x1.show()
    empty_df.show()
    user_belong_groups.show()
    user_belong_groups = user_belong_groups.unionAll(x1)
    x1.show()
  }
  setGetGroupsVars("obj_id", obj_id.toString(), obj_type_specific_df)
  var obj_belong_groups: DataFrame = empty_df
  val obj_array = Array[String](obj_id.toString())
  val obj_levels = obj_type_specific_df.filter("id = '" + obj_id + "'").select("level").distinct().collect().map { x => x.getInt(0) }
  println(obj_levels.length)
  for (ob_lvl <- obj_levels) {
    obj_belong_groups = obj_belong_groups.unionAll(getGroups(obj_array, ob_lvl))
  }
  user_belong_groups = user_belong_groups.distinct()
  obj_belong_groups = obj_belong_groups.distinct()
  var user_obj_joined_df = user_belong_groups.join(obj_belong_groups)
  user_obj_joined_df.show()

  println("vbgdivsivbfb")
  var user_obj_access_df = user_obj_joined_df
    .join(sa_other_access_df, user_obj_joined_df("u_id") === sa_other_access_df("user_id")
      && user_obj_joined_df("obj_id") === sa_other_access_df("object_id"))
  user_obj_access_df.show()
  println("KDDD..")

  val user_obj_access_cond1 = user_obj_access_df.filter("u_id = '" + user_id + "' and obj_id != '" + obj_id + "'")
  if (user_obj_access_cond1.count() == 0) {
    val user_obj_access_cond2 = user_obj_access_df.filter("u_id != '" + user_id + "' and obj_id = '" + obj_id + "'")
    if (user_obj_access_cond2.count() == 0) {
      val user_obj_access_cond3 = user_obj_access_df.filter("u_id != '" + user_id + "' and obj_id != '" + obj_id + "'")
      if (user_obj_access_cond3.count() == 0) {
        default_df
      } else {
        val result_ugrp_to_objgrp = user_obj_access_cond3.select("permission").agg(max("permission"))
        println("cond4")
        result_ugrp_to_objgrp
      }
    } else {
      val result_ugrp_to_ob = user_obj_access_cond2.select("permission")
      println("cond3")
      result_ugrp_to_ob
    }
  } else {
    val result_u_to_obgrp = user_obj_access_cond1.select("permission")
    println("cond2")
    result_u_to_obgrp
  }
} else {
  println("cond1")
  individual_access
}
```

These two are major code block in my prog where the execution is taking too longer. It generally takes much time at show or count operation.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: ok@eliasah.. what other things are needed to be more specific.. can u plz suggest..

Comment: Specify the code and Structure of data.

Comment: please provide your code or even better the most computation demanding part of your code.

Comment: I have added code samples.@sumit & GameofThrows.  I don't think structure of data will be needed. but still i am using 3 tables with less than 10 rows and table is about having 10 columns. I am not processing any data with the DB query. I am creating Dataframe first and then applying joins,collect,filter,count,show etc. to get the required results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First you can check in GUI that which stage of your program is taking long time.
- Second is you are using `distinct()` many times, So while use `distinct()` you have to look how many number of partitions are comes after distinct. I thought that's the reason why spark creating thousand of jobs.
- If that is the reason you can use `coalesce()` after `distinct()`.

Comment: Thanks @karmadip.. You are right.. distinct is creating 200 partitions at once, and then when i perform join 40,000 (200 * 200, as i am performing join on two dataframe with distinct method and lazy loading nature) task is created in single job. Your solution for **coalesce()**  is efficient and now my programs working normally. But the thing is still mystery for me that why **distinct()** is creating that much partitions while my dataframe just having about 10 rows..??

Comment: There are many configuration options  for performance tuning in spark, you can set it as your requirement. One is "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" and it's default value is 200. May be that's why you are getting 200 participation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's remember some basics !

**Spark** is a *lazy*, and `show` and `count` are actions.

An action triggers transformations, which you have loads of. And in case you are pooling data from Cassandra (or any other source) this cost a lot since you don't seem to be caching your transformations !

So, *you need to consider caching when you compute intensively* on a DataFrame or RDD, that will make your actions get performed faster !

Concerning the reason why you have that many tasks (jobs) is of-course explain by spark parallelism mechanism to perform you actions times the number of transformations/actions you are executing, not mentioning the loops !

Nevertheless, still with the information given and the quality of the code snippets posted in the question, this is as far as my answer goes.

I hope this helps !

Comment: i used .cache() but it didn't affect much. it reduces my time like 30 secs sometime. and it didn't reduce the number of jobs. And there are few places in my prog where i can use them because i mostly have var (not val) so i think its pointless to use .cache() there.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, your code is huge and with the information given, that's all I can give you.